Electromagnetics - Calculating electric field vector given an equipotential surface
I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the electric field vector given an equipotential surface with the equation \$ x^3 + y^2 +z = 1000 \$ where x, y, z are positive. The potential on the surface is 200V. If magnitude of electric field |E| = 50 at P(7,25,32) on the surface, determine the electric field vector E at P.
The problem with attempting a solution is that there is no equation for the potential in terms of x and y, z with which one would use the equation \$ E = - \nabla V \$,  where the operator \$ \nabla = \frac{\partial }{\partial x}a_{x} + \frac{\partial }{\partial y}a_{y} + \frac{\partial }{\partial z}a_{z}\$ The equation of the surface is given. The electric field parallel to the surface  at any location on the surface is zero.
Reference:
Engineerng electomagnetics, Hayt and Buck, 8e, McGrawhill, page 99.

Small hint:
What other properties do you know about equipotential surfaces?
Bigger hint:

 The field direction is perpendicular (normal) to the surface.  We are given the magnitude; only the direction needs to be found. 

 The potential on the surface seems to be a red herring: there is no other surface indicated in the quoted text to which electric field could drop; or at best, an assumed 0V reference at infinity. Solving the complete field strength around an arbitrary surface seems a much too difficult method. 

 (As an aside, it would be interesting to check if the given surface does, in fact, exhibit such a field strength at the given point, in such an environment.  Is the problem even internally consistent? Sometimes they aren't. :) )

Solution:

 The tangent to a point on a surface, is the gradient of the surface. 

 We can simply implicitly differentiate, for a surface \$f(x, y, z) = C\$: 
$$ \vec{n} = \nabla f = \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \right) $$
 or \$\left(3x^2, 2y, 1\right)\$.  Given \$x = 7\$, \$y = 25\$, \$z = 32\$, we have (147, 50, 1).  Finally, we normalize \$\hat{n} = \frac{\vec{n}}{|\vec{n}|}\$ and multiply by 50 to set the magnitude as given.  Evidently, \$\vec{E} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{24110}} \left( 7350, 2500, 50 \right) \$ (if a bit messy of a result). 

 I don't think there's a disambiguation for direction here, or perhaps we assume both (normal out of either side of the surface), as the surface is infinitesimally thick and the field extends from both sides of it (and it's an open surface); but in any case, that's a trivial sign change, or we might write it as ± to indicate the ambiguity.


It is unknown in which direction the potential is increasing or decreasing at P whether it increases or decreases normal and exterior to the surface or to the interior of the surface ..This information was omitted in the book.  A ± sign for the electric field is appropriate..
